# How can I Remove Grub on Startup from my Dual Boot Without Removing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, grub-legacy

I dual booted ubuntu with my windows 11 pc but I don't want my pc to display the grub screen everytime I turn it on and ask for my os choice as I want it to boot directly to windows but when required i can go to boot options by pressing F9 on system startup and run ubuntu. Is it possible?

Comment: If both are UEFI installs, you should just change UEFI settings, (not in boot menu) to have Windows first in boot order. Then when you want Ubuntu press f9.

Comment: @oldfred Why not just tailor GRUB? See my answer.

Comment: You want to keep GRUB. View this guide for seeing how to access boot settings (which will change UEFI boot order) https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/best-ways-access-windows-10-boot/ Hope it helps

Comment: @heynnema Your solution is fine if OP still wants grub menu, but Windows as default. But still should have 3 sec or more as timeout setting, so as to have some time to choose Ubuntu. And some Windows updates will turn fast start up back on, then grub will not boot Windows and you have to use UEFI boot menu, so you can turn fast start up back off.

Comment: @oldfred Huh? You can set GRUB menu to be completely hidden (this is what OP asked for). On a UEFI computer, you'd use ESC to show the GRUB menu. You can set it to default boot to Windows (this is what OP asked for) or Ubuntu... or ANY GRUB selection when using SAVEDEFAULT and it'll remember the last choice you made, and boot to it until you manually select a different choice.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these settings in /etc/default/grub, then `sudo update-grub`.

Clipped from `info -f grub`...

'GRUB_DEFAULT'

```
 The default menu entry.  This may be a number, in which case it
 identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero,
 or the title of a menu entry, or the special string 'saved'.  Using
 the id may be useful if you want to set a menu entry as the default
 even though there may be a variable number of entries before it.

 For example, if you have:

 menuentry 'Example GNU/Linux distribution' --class gnu-linux --id example-gnu-linux {
    ...
 }

 then you can make this the default using:

      GRUB_DEFAULT=example-gnu-linux

 Previously it was documented the way to use entry title.  While
 this still works it's not recommended since titles often contain
 unstable device names and may be translated

 If you set this to 'saved', then the default menu entry will be
 that saved by 'GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT' or 'grub-set-default'.  This
 relies on the environment block, which may not be available in all
 situations (*note Environment block::).

 The default is '0'.
```

'GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT'

```
 If this option is set to 'true', then, when an entry is selected,
 save it as a new default entry for use by future runs of GRUB. This
 is only useful if 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved'; it is a separate option
 because 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved' is useful without this option, in
 conjunction with 'grub-set-default'.  Unset by default.  This
 option relies on the environment block, which may not be available
 in all situations (*note Environment block::).
```

'GRUB_TIMEOUT'

```
 Boot the default entry this many seconds after the menu is
 displayed, unless a key is pressed.  The default is '5'.  Set to
 '0' to boot immediately without displaying the menu, or to '-1' to
 wait indefinitely.

 If 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE' is set to 'countdown' or 'hidden', the
 timeout is instead counted before the menu is displayed.
```

'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE'

```
 If this option is unset or set to 'menu', then GRUB will display
 the menu and then wait for the timeout set by 'GRUB_TIMEOUT' to
 expire before booting the default entry.  Pressing a key interrupts
 the timeout.

 If this option is set to 'countdown' or 'hidden', then, before
 displaying the menu, GRUB will wait for the timeout set by
 'GRUB_TIMEOUT' to expire.  If <ESC> is pressed during that time, it
 will display the menu and wait for input.  If a hotkey associated
 with a menu entry is pressed, it will boot the associated menu
 entry immediately.  If the timeout expires before either of these
 happens, it will boot the default entry.  In the 'countdown' case,
 it will show a one-line indication of the remaining time.
```